# Iterate over list elements in Pandas dataframe column and match with values in a different dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have two dataframes, I want to iterate over the elements in each list in the Companies column and match it with the company names in my second dataframe only if the date from the first dataframe occurs after the date of the second dataframe. I want two columns for the name matches and two columns for the date matches returned.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['Customer','Companies', 'Date'])
df = df.append({'Customer':'Gold', 'Companies':['Gold Ltd', 'Gold X', 'Gold De'], 'Date':'2019-01-07'}, ignore_index=True)
df = df.append({'Customer':'Micro', 'Companies':['Microf', 'Micro Inc', 'Micre'], 'Date':'2019-02-10'}, ignore_index=True)


Customer    Companies                     Date
0   Gold    [Gold Ltd, Gold X, Gold De] 2019-01-07
1   Micro   [Microf, Micro Inc, Micre]  2019-02-10


df2 = pd.DataFrame(columns=['Companies', 'Date'])
df2 = df2.append({'Companies':'Gold Ltd', 'Date':'2019-01-01'}, ignore_index=True)
df2 = df2.append({'Companies':'Gold X', 'Date':'2020-01-07'}, ignore_index=True)
df2 = df2.append({'Companies': 'Gold De', 'Date':'2018-07-07'}, ignore_index=True)
df2 = df2.append({'Companies':'Microf', 'Date':'2019-02-18'}, ignore_index=True)
df2 = df2.append({'Companies':'Micro Inc', 'Date':'2017-09-27'}, ignore_index=True)
df2 = df2.append({'Companies':'Micre', 'Date':'2018-12-11'}, ignore_index=True)

Companies         Date
0   Gold Ltd    2019-01-01
1   Gold X      2020-01-07
2   Gold De     2018-07-07
3   Microf      2019-02-18
4   Micro Inc   2017-09-27
5   Micre       2018-12-11


def match_it(d1, d2):
    for companies in d1['Companies']:
        for company in companies:
            if d2['Companies'].str.contains(company).any():
                mask = d1.Companies.apply(lambda x: company in x)
                dff = d1[mask]
                date1 = datetime.strptime(dff['Date'].values[0], '%Y-%m-%d').date()
                date2 = datetime.strptime(d2[d2['Companies']==company]['Date'].values[0], '%Y-%m-%d').date()

                if date2 < date1:
                    print(d2[d2['Companies']==company])
                    new_row = pd.Series([d2[d2['Companies']==company]['Date'], d2[d2['Companies']==company]['Companies']])
                    return new_row
```

Desired Output:

```
Customer    Companies                 Date       Name_1       Date_1      Name_2      Date_2    
Gold    [Gold Ltd, Gold X, Gold De] 2019-01-07   Gold Ltd   2019-01-01  Gold De      2018-07-07
Micro   [Microf, Micro Inc, Micre]  2019-02-10   Micro Inc  2017-09-27  Micre       2018-12-11
```

Comment: As I understood `Companies` list may have different lengths. What should be in this case? You will have a different number of columns(`Name_X`)

Comment: I think this question is very similar to yours: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53837685/merge-two-pandas-dataframe-on-a-cell-containing-a-list

You're looking to merge dataframes if `df2.Companies in df.Companies`. You'll just have some extra logic to drop columns in the output df if the date is not after the second date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start from more pandasonic way to convert *Date* columns in both DataFrames
from *string* do *datetime*:

```
df.Date = pd.to_datetime(df.Date)
df2.Date = pd.to_datetime(df2.Date)
```

Then proceed as follows:

```
df3 = df.explode('Companies')
df3 = df3.merge(df2, on='Companies', suffixes=('_x', ''))
df3 = df3[df3.Date_x > df3.Date].drop(columns='Date_x')
df3.rename(columns={'Companies': 'Name'}, inplace=True)
df3['idx'] = df3.groupby('Customer').cumcount()
df3 = df3.pivot(index='Customer',columns='idx')
df3 = df3.swaplevel(axis=1)
df3 = df3.sort_index(axis=1, ascending=[True, False])
cols = []
for i in range(1, df3.columns.size // 2 + 1):
    cols.extend(['Name_' + str(i), 'Date_' + str(i)])
df3.columns = cols
result = df.merge(df3, how='left', left_on='Customer', right_index=True)
```

The result is just as you want.

To comprehend the details run each instruction separately and print the result.
It is better to see the result on your own than read the description.

Caution: *Explode* is a relatively new function, added in *Pandas* version
*0.25*. If you have older version of *Pandas*, start from upgrading it.

## Edit following the comment as of 03:25:19Z

*df1* can have more columns.

To test it, I added *Xxx* column to *df1*.
The only change required in this case is to block these additional columns
from copying to *df3*. To do this, the first instruction should be appended with:

```
.drop(columns=['Xxx'])
```

(in general case, replace *'Xxx'* with the actual list of additional columns).

To check the case of different number of output columns, I changed the *Date*
for *Gold X* company in *df2* to *2019-01-06*, so that this company will
also be included in the output.

For your data, with the above changes, the result is:

```
  Customer                    Companies       Date   Xxx     Name_1     Date_1  Name_2     Date_2   Name_3     Date_3
0     Gold  [Gold Ltd, Gold X, Gold De] 2019-01-07  Xxx1   Gold Ltd 2019-01-01  Gold X 2019-01-06  Gold De 2018-07-07
1    Micro   [Microf, Micro Inc, Micre] 2019-02-10  Xxx2  Micro Inc 2017-09-27   Micre 2018-12-11      NaN        NaT
```

So, as you can see:

- The result contais also the added column (*Xxx*).
- The output contains also *Name_3* and *Date_3* columns.
- As for the second row from *df1* only 2 matches have been found,
  these columns contain here *NaN* and *NaT* (*Pandas* counterparts
  for *None*).

Comment: wow that's a great answer, thank you! Just one question, what if the first dataframe had more columns? Is there a way to preserve those while adding in the Name and Date Columns?